# Why does the linearity of $\varphi$ imply that $\varphi=-id$?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, orthogonality

[image]

Suppose we have an orthogonal (i.e. in particular linear and bijective) mapping $\varphi$ from the cube on itself with $\varphi(B)=B', \varphi(A)=A', \varphi(C)=C',\varphi(D)=D'$ and $\varphi(B')=B,\varphi(A')=A,\varphi(C')=C,\varphi(D')=D$.

It is said that the linearity of $\varphi$ implies $\varphi=-id$.

How can we see this?

I only see that for example
$$
\varphi(A)=A',\varphi(A')=A\implies \varphi(A)=\varphi(\varphi(A'))=A'\text{ and }\varphi(A')=\varphi(\varphi(A))=A,
$$
i.e. $\varphi^2(A)=A$ and $\varphi^2(A')=A'$, and similarly for the other point, i.e.
$$
\varphi^2=id
$$

Comment: Since $\phi$ is a linear map on $\mathbb R^3$, it is sufficient to show that $\phi v=-v$ for three linearly independent vectors $v$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The vectors $A,B,C$ form a basis for $\mathbb{R}^3$ (where the origin is the center of the cube). $\varphi$ is linear and therefore determined by its action on that basis, and $\varphi(A) = -A$, $\varphi(B) = -B$, $\varphi(C) = -C$.